Installing Intel TBB on Mac OS Big Sur
Due to certain dependencies, we are restricted to Mac OS Big Sur for the moment. We are trying to install Intel tbb via Homebrew with brew install tbb but failing with the following error. Based on the error message, it appeared to us Homebrew is trying to install Python 3.13.0, looks for Tkinter for the same, and is unable to find. So we tried to do brew install python-tk. Homebrew decided that Python 3.13.0 is a dependency, and decided to install the latter first, and so we are stuck in a cycle. Could you see where we are going wrong, and how we could fix this issue so as to have tbb up and running? Thank you very much!
==> Installing dependencies for tbb: python-setuptools, python@3.13, pcre2, swig and hwloc
==> Installing tbb dependency: python-setuptools
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/python-setuptools/manifests/75.6.0
Already downloaded: /Users/senthil/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/78d060d30c6c92fd7d0f6232745566828cf6b8bc6c56732c79acd6daf82d7fda--python-setuptools-75.6.0.bottle_manifest.json
==> Pouring python-setuptools--75.6.0.all.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/python-setuptools/75.6.0: 984 files, 8.2MB
==> Installing tbb dependency: python@3.13
Warning: Your Xcode (12.5.1) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 13.2.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

==> Patching
==> Applying 3.13-sysconfig.diff
==> ./configure --enable-ipv6 --datarootdir=/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/share --datadir=/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/s
==> make
==> make install PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1
Last 15 lines from /Users/senthil/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python@3.13/03.make:
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_socket.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/syslog.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/syslog.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/termios.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/termios.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_posixshmem.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_posixshmem.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_multiprocessing.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_multiprocessing.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_ctypes.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_curses.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_curses.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_curses_panel.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_curses_panel.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_sqlite3.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_ssl.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_hashlib.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_uuid.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_uuid.cpython-313-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_tkinter.cpython-313-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.13/3.13.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-313-darwin.so
install: Modules/_tkinter.cpython-313-darwin.so: No such file or directory
make: *** [sharedinstall] Error 71


[Not expert in mac/brew]
Seems brew doesn't have a binary package for this version and trying to build it.
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘, pkgconf ✘, python-setuptools ✘, python@3.13 ✘, swig ✘
Required: hwloc ✔

Maybe you can try to limit TBB version or you can just build it by yourself, from source

Did you do: Please update to Xcode 13.2.1 (or delete it), does it change anything ?

Thanks @ntfs.hard. Could you explain how to "limit TBB version"? Thank you.

@MauriceMeyer , It appears for Big Sur, we are stuck with Xcode 12.5.1. It seems upgrading Xcode beyond this would mean upgrading the OS first. Unfortunately, we are unable to delete it because of other dependencies.
